# Problem after exporting javaFx project that use postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, executable-jar

I'm working on a little javaFx that use postgresql.
When I execute the main by the IDE(Intellij) there are no problem and everything works fine, but when I export the executable jar it doesn't work any more. I tryed using sqlite as Database and there are no problem even after the export.
These are the error:

```
    WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @58daf476'
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at main.db_controll.DbConnection.connect(DbConnection.java:11)
        at main.db_controll.QueryAdmin.fetchAdminData(QueryAdmin.java:15)
        at main.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:75)
.....
....
...
```

This is my Database Connector:

```
public class DbConnection {
    public static Connection connect(){
        try {
            /*
            This work fine for sqlite
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:DbLibri.db";
            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, psw);
             */

            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DbLibri";
            String user = "postgres";
            String psw = "pass";

            return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, psw);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

All libraries are in the correctly imported in the project becase **It works from the IDE**.

Comment: your project is maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that come in mind. If you are using ant build, make sure the lib folder is in the same location as your jar.
If your are using maven, make sure you are building with dependencies. Run from cmd `mvn clean compile assembly:single` inside your working directory. Also you can added your pom.xml,

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass><your.main.class></mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>                         
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also sometimes there is a mismatch between the IDE java and the java used to run the jar file. Make sure they are the same or at least close enough.

Comment: By default Intellij use ant Build (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ant.html), so i have to palce the executable jar in the same directory of the lib folder? The problem is that i don't have a lib folder, I imported libraries(jar files) form my file system. Should I create a folder named lib in the same place of the executable jar and put there all my libraires that i included in my project ?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with intellij, but there should be a build folder, where your jar file is and a lib folder, containing all of your libs. Check out your project properties. There should be something like copy dependent libraries under packaging.

Comment: I tryed to find this folder but i really can't find it, I hope to solve this problem soon.

Comment: In you project properties there should be a libraries tab or category. There I think should be a option to set libraries folder.

Comment: I finally solved this problem, the problem was that I selected the wrong folder in the artifacts setup, now I selected the folder that contains the library and now it works fine. Thanks for your help.